# Search service application is not crawling for only one site collection?

Tags: search, enterprise-search

In our SharePoint 2010 environment, Search service application is not crawling for a site collection alone and it crawls for the other sitecollections are in the same contentDB.

Have verified the site collection search settings and found those are fine.

Verified in the crawl log and found that it throws “337” error while crawling the site collection and stopped.
[image]

I guess, 337 refers to "The server is unavailable and could not be accessed. The server is probably disconnected from the network."

Comment: Try to re-index your sites from start, also did you made any kind of changes before managing to get this error.

Comment: What are the error messages? Are all of them the same?

Comment: Please have a look, attached is the error screen shot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the site collection on the same physical server as your Central Administration / Search Service? If so, I had an issue similar to yours but the error was different.  It had to do something with the search service being on the same machine as my site collections. After doing some research, someone mentioned this KB article:

[You receive error 401.1 when you browse a Web site that uses Integrated Authentication and is hosted on IIS 5.1 or a later version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)

I followed the step in method 1, going to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0, creating a multi-string value BackConnectionHostNames and added each of my site collections' host names to that registry value (each host on a separate line), restarted IIS and then the search was able to index the site collection.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your crawler service account doesn't have access to read that specific site.

Comment: The crawler service account is provided with the full read access on the webapplication. Even accessed the site collection with that account to ensure this.

Comment: OK here are a few questions back :)
Are alternate access mappings ?
And what authentication are you using on your web app ?

Comment: This issue is specific to this site collection alone....anyway, we are using Windows Integrated authentication and AAM is in place...